# C++ - Interaction between move construction and forwarding

Tags: c++, perfect-forwarding, stdmove, construction

If I'm constructing a non-trivial container like a custom map for example,
and want to share code between the `emplace` and `insert` functions, one approach would be to have the `insert` function simply call `emplace` with the supplied element as the argument.
eg.:

```
template<typename... args>
iterator emplace(int id, args &&... params)
{
    // Do complex stuff here, get a location
    *location = value_type(std::forward<args>(params) ...);
}


iterator insert(int id, const value_type &element)
{
    emplace(id, element);
}
```

Which in the case of `insert &` should simply call the copy constructor if I understand correctly?
However in the case of `insert &&` it becomes a little more confusing:

```
iterator insert(int id, value_type &&element)
{
    emplace(id, std::move(element));
}
```

`std::move` casts element to an xvalue, which is fine - but will `std::forward` handle this appropriately? ie. for a non-trivial `value_type` with a non-default move constructor, will the `emplace` construction line above correctly call the move constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which in the case of `insert &` should simply call the copy constructor if I understand correctly?

Yes, you're giving `std::forward` a const lvalue in this scenario, and `std::forward` yields a const lvalue.
With that, the copy constructor is called.

> `std::move` casts element to an xvalue, which is fine - but will `std::forward` handle this appropriately?

Yes. `std::forward` turns rvalues into xvalues and lvalues into lvalues.
As long as you don't hand it an lvalue, it won't give you an lvalue.
This subsequently means that the move constructor will be called, as intended.

In `args &&... params`, `args` deduces to `value_type`, making `params` an rvalue reference when the function template is instantiated.
The [first overload of `std::forward`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward) is called, and `std::forward<args>(params)` yields an xvalue.

It's actually quite common to implement `push_back` or `insert` for containers in terms of `emplace_back` or `emplace`.

Comment: The explanation is wrong. The second overload is only called when a rvalue is passed to `std::forward`, but `params` is a lvalue. In practice, the second overload is seldom ever called.

Comment: @WeijunZhou you're right, I've fixed that now.